# How to auto implement protocol methods in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, function, protocols, implementation

When I was programming on eclipse, I remember that there was an option to auto implement interface methods (first implement the interface in the class and then implements methods right mouse clicking in the class body). Is there any similar option for to auto implement protocol methods in Xcode? I think that could be a cool features, saving lots of time...
Thanks a lot to everyone that have any "solutions" to my trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the same as Eclipse but you can take advantage of XCode Code Snippets feature once configured ... see https://github.com/burczyk/XcodeSwiftSnippets 
http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/
to get examples on how to

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm quite amazed tha Xcode does not have an useful feature like this (maybe i had programmed a long time with eclipse :) )